# How can you reset all the vuex states using the vue devtools?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

In Redux dev tools, you are able to reset all the states in redux store. How can I achieve the same with vuex in the vue devtools?

[image]

Comment: It's not possible to reset a Vuex module from the Vue Dev Tools. But you can develop a plugin that adds this featured: https://devtools.vuejs.org/plugin/plugins-guide.html :)